# Dropdown not relative to trigger element

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a list of items, each one has it's own 'settings' option. On click of the options, a dropdown (powered by http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/) displays. However, the dropdown is well below the trigger point (see image). And if you scroll the page vertically, then click an option button, the dropdown is at nearly the top of the page (so far up it's out of view).

This only occurs in the management area of the site so I can't give a link to view the issue/source code. I suspect it has something to do with the height of the window relative to the position of the trigger element. I attempted setting the class to `dropdown-relative` as per source FAQ's yet it has the same outcome.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this? Please let me know if further info is needed.

Code for trigger:

```
<div class="venue">
    <a href="#" data-dropdown="#dropdown-'.$v->id.'">Options</a>
</div>
```

Code for hidden element that displays on click:

```
<div id="dropdown-'.$v->id.'">
    <form and dropdown content is here>
</div>
```

CSS from dropdown

```
element.style {
     display: block;
     left: 469.083px;
     top: 327px;
 }
.dropdown {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 9999999;
 }
```

Image of issue
[image: Dropdown issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: absolute;` in your .dropdown class will stop it from dynamically changing it's location based on where you are in the page, try removing that.

Comment: This worked (with a small addition)! I made it `position: fixed;` and it did what you mentioned about changing location based on the page. Thank you for your help with such a painful yet seemingly easy fix :) Cheers!